# Match other columns for Column Fill and Text Color to an other column

Tags: excel, fill, conditional-formatting

I was wondering if there was a way to match up Columns A and B, in this example with Column C, regarding color formatting. I used Conditional Formatting for Column C.

Is there any type of formula I could set up to match the color scheme of Column A and B to match that of Column C, without doing it manually?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to add a picture. The rule I made was a text specific rule, so for example if the cell contains the word Active I would make that cell blue. I was trying to make names in columns A and B match the color of cell c.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the example you are working with, the first thing that comes to mind is apply the same conditional formatting to to A and B that you do C.

So when C:C >= 3 then C:C is red
then apply the same to A and B
When C:C >= 3 then A:A is red
When C:C >= 3 then B:B is red

You could also use a VB macro to copy the formatting but that would be a lot more work doesn't sound like it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

An example that converts a text rule (one that formats only the cells containing a specific string) into a formula rule that may apply to cells other than the trigger ones.

Select ColumnsA:C and:

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$C1="Active"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting, OK, OK.

[image: SO32534463 example]